# Write dynamically-defined python function to file

Tags: python, function, file, dynamic, export

Consider:

```
def func_create(default_val):
    def the_function():
        print("The default value is: %s" % default_val)
    return the_function

new_f = func_create(1.0)
new_f()
```

Which prints the line:

```
The default value is: 1.0
```

Is there a way to export the dynamically-created `new_f` to a file? pickle does not work, because the function is not hashable, but does this mean it's impossible?

Ideally, after exporting a function, you would be able to run something like:

```
from new_function_module import new_f
new_f()
```

and it would print the line

```
The default value is: 1.0
```

For bonus points, is there any method/library for python that replicates behaviour similar to Matlab's [matlabFunction](https://au.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.matlabfunction.html)? That is, exports *human-readable* python code to a file (as opposed to something like a pickle object)?

Comment: Even if there was a subset of functions that were exportable, that would be really useful to know...

Comment: It sounds like your goal is simply to output Python code as text with certain substitutable placeholders. Use a template engine like [`jinja2`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) in that case.

Comment: Don't let the example mislead you - I've deliberately created the example to be as simple as possible. Nonetheless, your answer is a good one :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specific non-simple features you need for which a template would not be enough? You can always import the generated file as a module to actually execute the functions within.

Comment: Well I'll admit that I don't know much about templating, but I'm assuming that by what you said - "like your goal is simply to output Python code as text with certain substitutable placeholders" that it's easy to find the limits. Extensions from the above example include positional and keyword arguments for the enclosed function, as well as functions dependent on other functions, and potentially even recursive functions. Broadly speaking, the more generalisable, the better.

Comment: A template is just a regular string with certain placeholders and/or markings to indicate what and how they get substituted by input values when producing an output. The Python code generated this way is no different in limits from any Python code you write yourself. The only possible scenario where you may not use a template is when you don't own the source code of a function object you obtain from a third party.

Answer (score 1):

Templates would the the right solution, but for your simple case you can do this

```
def func_create(default_val):
    return f"""\
def the_function():
    print("The default value is: {default_val}")
"""

with open("new_function_module.py", "w") as f:
    f.write(func_create(1.0))

from new_function_module import the_function
the_function()
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach is to access to the source code of the declared function via for ex [`inspect.getsourcelines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) module from the standard library.

Depending on the complexity of the problem there could be several solution: refactoring the signature/body, regex, templating (as mentioned in the comments).

Here an example of usage in a decorator form where you can specify the `path` of the new file and `mode` of writing, default is append.

```
import inspect

def func_create(default_val, path='./new_function_module.py', mode='a'):
    def wrapper(func):
        def __wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            new_src = (''.join(inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0][1:]) % default_val)
            with open(path, mode=mode) as fd:
                fd.write(new_src)
        return __wrapper
    return wrapper


@func_create(1.0)
def the_function():
    print("The default value is: %s")


print(the_function())
```

Note that `[0]` get the source lines, `[1:]` skips the `@func_create(1.0)` line in `inspect.getsourcelines(func)[0][1:]`